# How to output awk to pages instead of a list

Tags: mount, mountpoint

Basically I have put my Linux system into read only so I've only got command line. I am trying to output all mountpounts so I can remount the system drive as rw I have awk statement that gives the putput the problem is there more than one page and I cnt read the ones at the beginning so I am trying to find a way to output the data into pages I can read

To read the data as pages so I can find the mountpoint I need

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details (*are we to guess?*), and did you intentionally mount the system (*a file-system?*) to RO or did it *flip* to RO? (from RW) as that provide detail. Do you mean *file-system* or some other detail?  Please clarify & provide details.

Comment: It is xubuntu 22. It flipped to ro when booting. I mean the file system itself because it ro I cnt get x to start or do anything like edit fstab etc nor can I output awk to a text file because the system is ro

Comment: Please add additional details & clarifications to your question, but please note Xubuntu is a desktop release thus only releases products using the *year.month* format, ie. 22.04 or 22.10, and does not have releases that are *snap* only (ie. *year* or 22).  Please be precise with details, as Xfce isn't packaged for 22.

Comment: Xubuntu 22.04 is what I am using still to upgrade to 22.10

Comment: When a *file-system* flips from RW to RO, you should not try and change anything, as it *flips* from RW to RO to prevent dataloss, and you should be exploring logs, or be looking for clues as to why to fix whatever the problem is, ie. is a disk failing or other hardware issue, you've added something not built for your release & thus have corruption etc... System logs will contain clues which you should be exploring (or checking drive health - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)

Comment: Ok thanks I will dig into the logs and post a new thread if I need to. How do I install smartmon it readonly. Sorry autocorrect

Comment: if you just want to paginate command output, pipe it through `less`

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers.

Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]